# Blurred lines HTML Canvas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I'm drawing groups of five lines, but the fifth of each group always appears blurred. This is the result:
[image]

And this is my JavaScript code:

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    context.moveTo(X, Y);
    context.lineTo(X + length, Y);
    context.stroke();
    Y += space; 
}
```

Comment: context.beginPath();
context.closePath();
Try adding beginPath before and close Path after your painting. the stroke

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
It is working fine. You have to provide us more details if this really don't work.

```js
((context) => {
  var length = 200, X = 10, Y = 10, space = 10;
  context.beginPath();
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    context.moveTo(X, Y);
    context.lineTo(X + length, Y);
    Y += space;
  }
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
})(document.querySelector("#canvas").getContext("2d"));
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #defcfa;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
```

**Old answer:**

Try it like this:

```
context.beginPath();
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  context.moveTo(X, Y);
  context.lineTo(X + length, Y);
  Y += space; 
}
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

Comment: But it is not blurring with my code. Please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Try Math.floor() :ing the coordinates.

Blurry drawings can be caused by coordinates with decimals!

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    context.moveTo( Math.floor( X ), Math.floor( Y ) );
    context.lineTo( Math.floor( X + length ) , Math.floor( Y ) );
    context.stroke();
    Y = Math.floor( Y + space ); 
}
```

Anyway.. I can't reproduce this problem myself, so may be browser or something else.

Also, are you using ctx.scale, ctx.translate or ctx.transform?

Comment: I tried to use Math.floor(), but nothing changed. And no, I'm not using scale, translate or transform...